# Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'PDOException' with message 'SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 1 in display.php line 44

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

Hi guys I can't fix this error and I don't know why it shows up
I checked my database and all columns exist,I don't know how to fix it , can somebody please help me.

This is my code

```
class Display extends Journeyholic {

private $tablename;
private $recData = array();

public function __construct($tablename) {

    $this->tablename = $tablename;

    $this->connectToDb();
}

function getAllData() {
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM `$this->tablename` ORDER BY `id` ASC";

    $query = $this->cxn->cxn->prepare($sql);

    $query->execute();
    $data = $query->fetchAll();

    return $data;
}

function getLastRecordDESC() {

    $sql = "SELECT * FROM `$this->tablename` ORDER BY `id` DESC LIMIT 1";
    $query = $this->cxn->cxn->prepare($sql);

    $query->execute();

    $data = $query->fetch();

    return $data;
}

function getRecordByID($id) {

    $id = intval($id);
 $sql = "SELECT * FROM `$this->tablename` WHERE `$id`=$id";
  $query = $this->cxn->cxn->prepare($sql);

    $query->execute();

    $this->recData = $query->fetch();

    return $this->recData;

}


function getAllDataByID($id, $column = "id") {

    $id = intval($id);
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM `$this->tablename` WHERE `$column`=$id";
    $query = $this->cxn->cxn->prepare($sql);

    $query->execute();

    $data = $query->fetchAll();

    return $data;
}
```

Following snap is my database :

[image: Database]

I also tried changing the backticks to single quotes but it is not working. I just need somebody to tell me what's exactly wrong and how to fix it?

Comment: Care to highlight the line 44?

Comment: On a side note, why you're using prepare and execute?

Comment: Looks like you confused variables order for getAllDataByID

Comment: Debug the functions where you are using function parameter as column names

Answer (score 2):

Main problem is here:

```
"SELECT * FROM `$this->tablename` WHERE `$id`=$id"
```

Should be so I guess:

```
"SELECT * FROM `$this->tablename` WHERE `id`= " . $id
```

Otherwise query would result in something like

```
"SELECT * FROM `$this->tablename` WHERE `12345`= 12345
```